# var_dump returns null.The login page gives a blank page

Tags: php, authentication, var-dump

Login page not working. A blank page appears after the user clicks login button even with the correct email and password. var_dump[$_POST] returns   array(10) { ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["login"]=> string(0) "" ["uname"]=> string(0) "" ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["puname"]=> string(0) "" ["pname"]=> string(0) "" ["pemail"]=> string(0) "" ["Partnerpassword"]=> string(0) ""

Here is my code

```
 <?php


   require_once("config.php");

   error_reporting(E_ALL); 
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);

   $id=$_POST['email'];

   $pass=$_POST['password'];
   var_dump($_POST);

  $stmt = $cn->prepare('SELECT Email,Password FROM register_partneruser WHERE Email = ? ');

  $stmt->bind_param('s', $id); 
  $stmt->execute();  




  $stmt->bind_result( $a,$Partnerpassword);

   if($stmt->fetch())

  {                                 
    //      var_dump($id,$a);

   //     var_dump($password,$Partnerpassword);

         if(password_verify($pass,$Partnerpassword))
      
        {
          
                echo "Login successfull"; 
         }
        else
        {
             echo"Login failed";
        }
              

     }


   else  
  {
      $error = "Username or Password is incorrect";
  }
```

?>

Here is the HTML code snippet of the login form

```
 <form class="js-validate" novalidate="novalidate" method="post">
                                        <!-- Login -->
                                        <div id="login" style="opacity: 1;" data-target-group="idForm" class="animated fadeIn">
                                            <!-- Header -->
                                            <div class="card-header text-center">
                                                <h3 class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-semi-bold">Login</h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- End Header -->
                                            <div class="card-body pt-6 pb-4">
                                                <!-- Form Group -->
                                                <div class="form-group pb-1">
                                                    <div class="js-form-message js-focus-state border border-width-2 border-color-8 rounded-sm">
                                                        <label class="sr-only" for="signinSrEmail">Email</label>
                                                        <div class="input-group input-group-tranparent input-group-borderless input-group-radiusless">
                                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="signinSrEmail" placeholder="Email Or Username" aria-label="Email Or Username" aria-describedby="signinEmail" required="" data-msg="Please enter a valid email address." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success">
                                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                                <span class="input-group-text" id="signinEmail">
                                                                    <span class="far fa-envelope font-size-20"></span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- End Form Group -->
                                                <!-- Form Group -->
                                                <div class="form-group pb-1">
                                                    <div class="js-form-message js-focus-state border border-width-2 border-color-8 rounded-sm">
                                                        <label class="sr-only" for="signinSrPassword">Password</label>
                                                        <div class="input-group input-group-tranparent input-group-borderless input-group-radiusless">
                                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="signinSrPassword" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password" aria-describedby="signinPassword" required="" data-msg="Your password is invalid. Please try again." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success">
                                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                                <span class="input-group-text" id="signinPassword">
                                                                    <span class="flaticon-password font-size-20"></span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- End Form Group -->
                                                <div class="mb-3 pb-1">
                                                    <button type="submit" name="login" formaction="../php/login.php"  method="post" class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-blue-1 rounded-xs font-weight-bold transition-3d-hover">Login</button>
                                                </div>
```

Comment: Try doing `print_r` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is your question wrong?

There is a difference between:

- `NULL` is returned and
- Nothing is returned at all

A few questions arise from this:

1. Who is running the web server?
2. Are you sure that you also have the right to set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and
   `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`?

Remove the code for the database query and the one for the password comparison and run the program again.

```
//$stmt = $cn->prepare('SELECT Email,Password FROM register_partneruser WHERE Email = ? ');
//$stmt->bind_param('s', $id); 
//$stmt->execute();
//$stmt->bind_result( $a,$Partnerpassword);
if( 1 ) //if($stmt->fetch())
{                                 
    //      var_dump($id,$a);
   //     var_dump($password,$Partnerpassword);    
        if( 1 ) //if(password_verify($pass,$Partnerpassword))
        {              
            echo "Login successfull"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo"Login failed";
        }         
    }
else  
{
    $error = "Username or Password is incorrect";
}
```

The program should now be running.
You can manually control/emulate via `if(1)` or `if(0)` whether a user has logged in or not.

If your program is running now, the error is not in this program, but:

- There is an SQL error
- Or something is wrong with your password comparison

I assume that the `Named Parameter` is the error, `$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);` : because it is only specified as `?` in the query.

The reason that you don't get an error is that you don't have the right to set the `Error Reporting` via `PHP`-script.

---

Edit 1 for question:

You didn't answer my questions: Who hosts the web server? If it is you, you have to change your `php.ini` and enable `error_reporting`.

Otherwise you have to look in the configuration of your web hoster, how to enable it, or ask him!

**Your question is wrong**! You should ask, how do I activate the error_reporting and also give the necessary information, where is hosted, which php-version, if apache webserver or another!

Comment: How to get the right to set the Error Reporting via PHP script. Please tell since I am a newbie don't know much about it. Also I modified my code and that's working yet the password comparison is not working...How should I fetch and compare hashed password since password_verify () is not working

Comment: I am not the one hosting the server. Thanks for that. I will try to enable error_reporting@raiserle

Comment: You should set the answer to accepted and then ask a new one if you can locate the error. Or if you need help to include error_report.

Comment: Removing bind_param() and password_verify() and Modifying the code Worked for another login form. But It did not work for the above Html form.Thanks anyways.

Comment: Also using hashed password in register form was causing issue in login form. It worked when I removed password hashing

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks ok, in fact, the output this is the output:

```
array(3) { ["email"]=> string(4) "test" ["password"]=> string(4) "test" ["login"]=> string(0) "" }
```

My guess is that your config.php is the out having issues.

Try this, comment out the include and comment out also everything after the var_dump, if you see the output, then that file is the ones giving you issues.

EDIT:
Try to debug your HTTP call, you can use the chrome debugger (f12-> click on network-> click on preserve log -> open your site and run the post)

You should see something like this:

Calls:

```
http://127.0.0.1/projects/localweb/so/

GET http://127.0.0.1/projects/localweb/so/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2021 21:15:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.3.23
Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Jan 2021 21:02:47 GMT
ETag: "11c1-5b869e0e0b909"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4545
Content-Type: text/html
http://127.0.0.1/projects/action.php
email: email@email.com
login: 
password: password

POST http://127.0.0.1/projects/action.php
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2021 21:15:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.3.23
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.23
Content-Length: 127
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Response:
array(3) { ["email"]=> string(15) "email@email.com" ["password"]=> string(8) "password" ["login"]=> string(0) "" }

There are no redirections or anything like that.

Are you running this on http or https? is the call being moved to https when posting? any other redirection on the http log?

Also, check your .htaccess, maybe your htaccess is rewriting something, adding slashes, something, remove it for testing, for sure you have something not-code-related.

Comment: It still returns the same output...null string@Marco

Comment: @RichaSingh, I added some edits to the response, check it out.

Comment: I am running this on https and I have checked my .htaccess file. It seems OK ,not sure about it...I am not getting the above response as yours@Marco

Comment: You have not located the problem! This answer has no benefit.